# Moq multiple instances are injecting the wrong properties

Tags: mocking, moq

I have the following contract which gets an injected property at runtime:

```
public interface IBroker
{
   IDriver Driver { get; }
}

public interface IDriver
{
   void Save();
}

public class FileDriver : IDriver { }
public class SqlDriver : IDriver { }
```

I am preparing my mocks in one shot because the test fitness is pretty big, and I am preparing two versions of my broker in the following way:

```
var mockFileBroker = new Mock<IBroker>();
mockFileBroker.Setup(x => x.Driver).Returns(new FileDriver());

var mockSqlBroker = new Mock<IBroker>();
mockSqlBroker.Setup(x => x.Driver).Returns(new SqlDriver());
```

The problem is that when I investigate the property **Driver** it is always of type SqlDriver for both mocks ... so it looks like **Moq** is always resolving the contract IDriver using the latest registration ...
Is there anything I can do to avoid this behavior?

Comment: There must be something else going on.  I just did a test using your interfaces and mock objects and the IDriver implementation I get back matches the one defined in the Setup.  But why not mock out the IDriver as well -- or is this more of an integration test?

Comment: Well it is not an integration test, I am testing the behavior of the Driver and not the broker so I need to mock the Broker because I don't want to access directly the Driver. So it looks like an integration test because it involves more than 1 object but in reality is still a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq will return the latest registration, but only on the same object.

Double check you are not using the wrong broker somewhere, or that you have missed a mock somewhere and production code is re-setting your Driver.

Patrick Steele makes a good point that you should also consider mocking the returned `IDriver` too, especially as unit tests should typically avoid using the file system and databases.

Comment: I know but the Driver gets injected an IConnection which is mocked too ... I am testing the code inside the method Save of IDriver for the differenc implementations.
Btw, I will check what is going on and what is causing the swap

Comment: I forgot to check my TestInitialize and TestTearDown. I was switching the instances that's why moq was resolving the wrong driver. Now it works!